# How can I give WKWebView a colored background

Tags: cocoa-touch, uikit, wkwebview

I'm working on an app in which I load different html files with mostly dark backgrounds. Right now there's a small white flash when navigating from one page to another, presumably since the next page has not loaded yet. I'd like to get rid of that flash and thought the most straightforward way would be to give the WebView a background color.

I tried setting the color for the WebView as well as the scrollView inside of it, but that doesn't seem to work:

```
self.webView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
self.webView?.scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
```

I see a flash of the color when the view is loaded the first time, but not on subsequent navigation.

Comment: How can we change background color to white ?

Answer (score 130):

To stop 'white flash' on your dark background, do this

```
webView.opaque = false
```

This doesn't really solve background colour issue, but at least it stops 'white flash' you are experiencing.
Apparently there seem to be no way to change background colour of WKWebView before loading HTML on it.

**Swift 4**

```
webView.isOpaque = false
```

Comment: How to change color to white ?

Comment: How do you make the initial background color of a WKWebView, say, purple?

Answer (score 27):

```
self.webView = WKWebView()
self.webView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.11, green:0.13, blue:0.19, alpha:1)
self.webView.scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.11, green:0.13, blue:0.19, alpha:1)
```

Don't forget that your `WKWebView` is an optional so maybe you don't init it.

Comment: Just setting the `scrollView` color did it for me

Answer (score 10):

I used to hide the WKWebView when I did the load request in one project.

```
webView.isHidden = true
webView.load(req)
```

When the load was completed I set the webView visible again.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    webView.isHidden = false
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
    activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    webView.isHidden = false
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Click on the `WKWebView` in soryboard, and choose preferred *Background* color from **attributes inspector panel**.

Then put `content.isOpaque = false` where your `WKWebView` is loaded from, for example in `viewDidLoad()`

```
@IBOutlet weak var content: WKWebView!
...
content.isOpaque = false
```

Comment: You can also instead uncheck the Opaque checkbox for the WKWebView in storyboard.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me in macOS 14

```
let webview = WKWebView()
webview.setValue(false, forKey: "drawsBackground")
```